# Oracle where exist slow update

Tags: oracle

I need to update TableA ColC where ColD is 'E'

```
TableA
```

From:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
 A       B      C     D
 A       B      S     F
 A       B      X     E
 Z       Y      W     H
```

To:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
 A       B      X     D
 A       B      X     F
 A       B      X     E
 Z       Y      W     H
```

I am using this

```
update tableA A
  set ColC = ( select ColC
               from   tableA B
               where  B.ColD = 'E'
               and    A.ColA = B.ColA
               and    A.ColB = B.ColB )
             where exist
             ( select 1
               from   tableA B
               where  B.ColD = 'E'
               and    A.ColA = B.ColA
               and    A.ColB = B.ColB )
```

There are total 400 rows to update.

Problem is it took almost 1 min to update.

Is there any more effective sql to do update?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer as to your intent?  The statement "I need to update TableA ColC where ColD is 'E'" isn't quite enough to describe, and it's a little tricky to read what your statement is intended to do (I suspect it's not quite the same as what it *actually* does)

Comment: Sorry is difficult to translate query into statement. But from the query I had you shall be able to see what I am trying to do.

Comment: Well what your SQL describes is, for each row in `tableA` set the value of `ColC` to that held in a random row in `tableA` where that row's `ColD` is set to E and `ColA` and `ColB` match the row to be updated.  And that doesn't sound like it's a reasonable thing to want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index on table tableA  for ColD, ColA, ColB columns.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tableA ON tableA (ColD, ColA, ColB);
```

Comment: Assuming 400 rows (as stated) on a narrow table (whilst it's only an example, the description is 4 columns each with a single char held), the whole of the table will likely sit in one block, meaning a FTS may *actually* be quicker than referencing by an index.  However, if the table storage size means an index is appropriate, then this is the appropriate index.

Answer (score 1):

It might be faster to just update all rows (performing a dummy update if the Subselect returns nothing):

```
update tableA A
   set ColC = coalesce((select ColC
                         from tableA B
                        where B.ColD = 'E'
                          and A.ColA = B.ColA
                          and A.ColB = B.ColB),
                       ColC);
```